# LibGdx Actor не реагирует на переход на другой экран

Tags: java, libgdx

Есть актёр, и по тапу он должен переходить на новый экран. Этого не происходит, однако вывод в консоль работает. С чем это связано и как это исправить?

```
@override
public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
    Gdx.app.log("Hi CLICK WORKING", "");
}

@override
public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Может экран не меняется потому, что просто нет кода для перехода на новый экран?

```java
@override
public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    Gdx.app.log("Hi CLICK WORKING", "");
    game.setScreen(myScreen);
}

@override
public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}
```